# vscode "Go to Symbol in Workspace" not working.

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode 1.20.1, and have `ctags` installed via `brew install ctags`; I'm using a virtualenv and my `python.pythonPath` is set correctly.

My **"Go to Symbol in File"** works fine, but I recently noticed that some of my symbols could not be resolved via **"Go to Symbol in Workspace"**.

I realized that the `./vscode/tags` file was not being updated.  If I delete the file and force VSCode to rebuild it, the symbols resolve properly.

This problem can be duplicated when I create a new project with 2 files.  The first time I use "Go to Symbol in Workspace", the `./vscode/tags` file is built, but adding any additional files does not force the `tags` file to get updated.

Has anyone else run into this problem before?

**Environment:** 
VSCode: 1.20.1
Python Extension: 2018.1.0
Python Version: 3.6.3
OS : Mac OSX 10.13.3 .

Comment: Are there any errors reported in the Output window? And I assume you have not tweaked any of the [workspace symbols settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_workspace-symbol-tags-settings)?

Comment: Nothing in the Output window.  I haven not modified any workspace symbols.

Comment: Nothing in `Toggle Developer Tools` pane either.

Comment: Turns out to be a known issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/793

Comment: Thanks...!  I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: Posted an official answer to make my answer a bit more discoverable and to help me remember that an answer was found :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/793) with the extension.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that; we're hoping to fix it for our March release which will (hopefully) be out at the end of the month.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue without messing with `ctags`.

This issue had occurred to me 2022 for last two weeks.
`"Go to Symbol in Workspace"` seemed to not work.
I have running wsl2 + ubuntu 22 Linux distribution with a nodejs/python project.

Pressing `Ctrl+T` didn't find any symbols.

This issue was resolved immediately after uninstalling some extensions. I don't remember explicitly which extension, but this should be your default goto when trying to fix this issue.
Additionally I recreated my vscode workspace, but I don't it contributed anything for this fix.